# Retrieving text (html node) from Javascript using R

Tags: javascript, r, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve the quote *"I understood at a very early age...spirit of the universe."* and the author's name *"Alice Walker"* from the following Javascript code:

```
<div id="qpos_4_3" class="m-brick grid-item boxy bqQt" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 33815px;">

 <div class="">

  <a href="/quotes/quotes/a/alicewalke625815.html?src=t_age" class="b-qt 
  qt_625815 oncl_q" title="view quote">I understood at a very early age that 
  in nature, I felt everything I should feel in church but never did. 
  Walking in the woods, I felt in touch with the universe and with the 
  spirit of the universe.

  </a>

  <a href="/quotes/authors/a/alice_walker.html" class="bq-aut qa_625815 
  oncl_a" title="view author">Alice Walker</a>

  </div>

  <div class="kw-box">

   <a href="/quotes/topics/topic_nature.html" class="oncl_k" data-
   idx="0">Nature</a>,

  </div>
```

I have used chrome's developer toolbar to get the xpath. The following code is intended to extract the quote, but it outputs `character(0)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
link <-  "https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_age.html"
quote <- read_html(link)

quote %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="qpos_4_3"]/div[1]/a[1]') %>% 
  html_attr('view quote')
```

Comment: _"You may not access, use, or copy any portion of the Site or its content through the use of bots, spiders, scrapers, web crawlers, indexing agents, or other automated devices or mechanisms. You agree not to remove or modify any copyright notice or trademark legend, author attribution, or other notice placed on or contained within any of the Site's content. Except as expressly authorized by us in writing, in no event will you reproduce, redistribute, duplicate, copy, modify, distribute…"_  Best read item 5 [here](https://www.brainyquote.com/about/terms).

Comment: It is meant for personal use only and for practicing creating bots, but thank you for pointing this out. I will be really careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there with your attempt. Note that you could extend your XPath expression to include the `title` you were trying to isolate with `html_attr` but you really wanted `xml_contents`. I've added `magrittr` only for piping and readability, it is not otherwise required... and I have coerced the results to characters assuming you will use them as such further on.

```
get_contents <- function(link, id, title) {

  require(xml2)
  require(magrittr)

  xpath <- paste0(".//div[@id='", id, "']//a[@title='", title, "']")

  read_html(link) %>%
    xml_find_first(xpath) %>%
    xml_contents() %>%
    as.character()

}

link <-  "https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_age.html"
id <- "qpos_1_10"

quote <- get_contents(link, id, "view quote")

# [1] "In our age there is no such thing as 'keeping out of politics.' All
# issues are political issues, and politics itself is a mass of lies,
# evasions, folly, hatred and schizophrenia."

author <- get_contents(link, id, "view author")

# [1] "George Orwell"
```